# How to add drop down box and search box in the bar plots created with cufflinks using pandas( ipython notebook)?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have plotted interactive bar plot using plotly's cufflinks (using pandas series). in offline  mode

Below is the code I am using for plotting :

```
cf.go_offline()  ## Use plotly in offline mode

df.iplot(kind='bar', xTitle = 'roles',yTitle='count', title='Bar Plot:', filename='cufflinks/categorical-bar-chart')
```

Here **df** is my series and **Role** is my index.(x-axis)

```
             Priority   Year    Avg_in_hrs         Total_in_Hrs
Role                        
 A           Medium     2015       34.4              34
 B           Low        2014       33.55             123
 C           High       2014       3                 4566
 D           Low        2015       12                3666
```

Now I want to add drop down list and search box for my x-axis labels i.e. for **roles** which is my pandas dataframe column having many values so that I can search and see only plot for that particular role. How do I add this ?

Also how to share these interactive plots with others like using web application so that I can maintain the interactivity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could move your `yaxis` `range` depending on the selected dropdown menu, i.e. if the user selects `A`, only the range specific for `A` is shown.

The code defines a dropdown entry for each `index` and one to reset the graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

roles = 'ABCDE'
prios = ['Medium', 'Low', 'High', 'Low', 'High']
years = [2015, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2014]
avgs = [34.4, 33.55, 3, 12, 15]
total_hours = [34, 123, 4566, 3666, 4000]

data = dict()
data['Prio'] = prios
data['Year'] = years
data['average'] = avgs
data['hours'] = total_hours

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = list(roles)
df.index.names = ['Role']

buttons = list()
offset = -0.5
for r in roles:
    buttons.append(dict(
        args=['xaxis.range', [offset, offset + 1]],
        label=r,
        method='relayout'  
    ))
    offset += 1
buttons.append(dict(
    args=['xaxis.range', [-0.5, offset]],
    label='Reset',
    method='relayout'  
))
layout = dict(updatemenus=list([
        dict(
            x=-0.05,
            y=0.8,
            buttons=buttons,
            yanchor='top'
        )
    ])
)
df.iplot(kind='bar', xTitle = 'roles',yTitle='count', title='Bar Plot:', filename='cufflinks/categorical-bar-chart', layout=layout)
```

Comment: thanks. I used your code to plot my original data set. It looks good. Just one more question all labels values i.e. priority,year etc. are not visible on y-axis  and in drop down list its not showing all labels. I got 64 different values for my roles index. Its better I should include search box as well for role.

Comment: as far as I know Plotly does not provide a free text search, you would need to implement that in Javascript yourself. The missing y-axis labels are a result of cufflinks. Cufflinks results in very short but if you want to have more control you would need to use Plotly's syntax.